# Problem with Nuxt3 Firebase Auth Middleware

Tags: firebase, vuejs3, nuxt3

In a Nuxt3 project I am using Firebase auth. I have created the following middleware to protect not authenticated routes:

```
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
    const { $auth } = useNuxtApp();
    const { $localePath } = useNuxtApp();

    if(!$auth?.currentUser?.uid){
        return navigateTo({ path: $localePath({name: 'auth-login'}) });
    }
});
```

Everything is working fine at first. I login, then I navigate in the application. But when I refresh the browser even thou I haven't logged out from the user profile I am redirected to the login page.

The `$auth?.currentUser?.uid` is returning `null`. I am storing the logged in user data in a firebaseUser store. However the same problem occurs when I try to get the state in the middleware. It tells me that I am not logged in and redirects me to the login page, but the user data is stored in the store.

How can I make the middleware to detect if I am logged in on refresh of the browser page?

This is my firebaseAuth:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth"

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
    
    const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
        authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
        projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJCT_ID,
        storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
        messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
        appId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
        measurementId: process.env.FIREBASE_MEASURMENT_ID,
    };

    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    // Init user
    initUser();

    // Get auth
    const auth = getAuth();

    nuxtApp.vueApp.provide('auth', auth);
    nuxtApp.provide('auth', auth);
})
```

And this is my initUser logic in useFirebase:

```
export const initUser = async () => {

    const auth = getAuth();
    const firebaseUser = useFirebaseUser();
    firebaseUser.value = auth.currentUser;

    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        firebaseUser.value = user;
    });
}
```

And my store:

```
export const useFirebaseUser = () => useState('firebaseUser', () =>{});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding async to your plugin and middleware as following:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
export default defineNuxtPlugin(async (nuxtApp) => {
const firebaseConfig = {
  // Your Firebase configuration here
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Get auth
const auth = getAuth();

// Wait for Firebase authentication to initialize
await new Promise((resolve) => {
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
      resolve(user);
    } else {
      resolve(null);
    }
  });
});

nuxtApp.vueApp.provide("auth", auth);
nuxtApp.provide("auth", auth);
```

});

and to your middleware as well so it looks like:

```
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async (to, from) => {
  const { $auth } = useNuxtApp();
  const { $localePath } = useNuxtApp();

  // Wait for Firebase authentication to initialize
  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    $auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user?.uid) {
        resolve();
      } else {
        navigateTo({ path: $localePath({ name: "auth-login" }) });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried it, but the application is not starting. There is an error:

[nitro] [unhandledRejection] Error: [nuxt] A composable that requires access to the Nuxt instance was called outside of a plugin, Nuxt hook, Nuxt middleware, or Vue setup function. This is probably not a Nuxt bug.

Comment: Hey, i have the same issue as @Don40.
When I tried your solution, i got this error when getting a page: 
Error 500: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onAuthStateChanged') in my middleware.

Comment: i have same issue, any new solution?

Answer (score -2):

I found some solution to the problem:

Not the "correct" solution but I got it working by checking for a cookie instead of waiting for the firebase initialization.

When the user creates and account or signs in, I set a cookie in the method with the value of the firebase user information:

```
  const response = await signInUser(email, password);

  const userCookie = useCookie("userCookie");

  userCookie.value = response;
```

Then in the plugins/auth.ts, I check for the cookie instead of the auth.currentUser:

```
addRouteMiddleware('auth', () => {
    const userCookie = useCookie("userCookie");

    if (!userCookie?.value?.user) {
        return navigateTo('/login')
    }

})
```

When the user signs out, I just set the cookie value to empty in the signOut method:

```
const userCookie = useCookie("userCookie");
userCookie.value = null;
```

I also do the same but to redirect a signed in user away from the sign-in page:

```
addRouteMiddleware('signedIn', () => {
        const userCookie = useCookie("userCookie");

        if (userCookie?.value?.user) {
            return navigateTo('/')
        }
    })
```